# How do i monitor/modify websocket (socket.io from nodeJS) data from fiddler?

Tags: javascript, sockets, network-programming, connection, fiddler

I'm curious because i can't monitor the socket.io connection.
I was thinking if i can modify the websocket data's like this :

```
//Server Script:
io.emit('text',"hello");
```

And then the Fiddler will modify the string to "Hi" So I will receive "Hi" instead of "Hello". If fiddler is not possible for this, then is there any application/software that i can use?

Comment: well from what im reading fiddler can read and manipulate http headers and connections. socket.io and websockets are using the ws/wss protocol which is nothing simular to http calls/connections. There are addons able to monitor ws connections. google just gave me this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/ 
there are probably others too.

Comment: this is for chrome https://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.